# QT QMainWindow from subroutine

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I have problems to create a QMainWindow object from a subroutine. I need this to create a different number of windows on the user's request.

The problem lies in the fact that if I create it from a subroutine, it is created as a local variable and only shows for a split second. Usually I would need to return a pointer, but I have not managed to do it with this object. Here is the code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

QMainWindow runGUI(){
    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();
    window.resize(340,260);
    return window;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    /*
    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();
    window.resize(340,260);
    */
    runGUI();
    return app.exec();
}
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: _"Usually I would need to return a pointer, but I have not managed to do it with this object"_ can you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, in your `main` you are not using returned of `runGUI()` so it is destroyed before `app.exec()`

Comment: And, can you please elaborate on _"I need this to create a different number of windows on the user's request"_ You need different number of main windows?

Comment: @mvidelgauz the runGUI() routine doesn't compile ( it says error: 'QMainWindow::QMainWindow(const QMainWindow&)' is private ).

I tried putting `*runGUI();` with `return &window;` and calling `QMainWindow *window = runGUI();`

Comment: I also tried changing to a void routine, which compiles, but then the window banishes in a split second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning your QMainWindow from runGUI() calls the copy constructor: Qt objects are not designed to be copied. You should indeed return a pointer, and dynamically allocate the window:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

QMainWindow* runGUI(){
    QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow;
    window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    window->show();
    window->resize(340,260);
    return window;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow* window = runGUI();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Note the use of `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` to ensure the window will be deleted when it is closed, avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: Actually for this code, returning the pointer is unnecessary (and there should be a compiler warning about unused variable ´window´ from main).

Comment: For this code, you're right. But returning the pointer is necessary in the use case of the OP, although this use case is not really shown in its example and in my so-derived answer